# Collection based Generics and Reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

So heres my problem. I have two classes...SingularEntity and a ListEntity. As the name suggests, SingularEntity represents an Entity and a ListEntity represents a List of Singular Entities....the list obviously has more common properties than the SingularEntity itself. So I have an AuthorizationEntity which extends the SingularEntity class

```
public class SingularEntity{
}

public class AuthorizationEntity extends SingularEntity{

}
```

Now I have a single ListEntity which represents a List of any SingularEntities

```
public class ListEntity{

  public List<? extends SingularEntity> data;

  public ListEntity(List<? extends SingularEntity> data){
        this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to use reflection to populate a list always....and I always run into an error in the results.add method. Says that method List.add(CAP#1) is not applicable. Any help is gladly appreciated

```
public List<? extends SingularEntity> build() {
            List<? extends SingularEntity> results = new ArrayList<SingularEntity>();
            try {

                Constructor javaBeanClassConstructor =
                        (Constructor) DTOClass.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
                Class<?>[] constructorParameterTypes =
                        javaBeanClassConstructor.getParameterTypes();


                for (Object[] columns : lstInput) {
                    Object[] constructorArgs = new Object[constructorParameterTypes.length];
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
                        Object columnValue = columns[j];
                        Class<?> parameterType = constructorParameterTypes[j];
                        // convert the column value to the correct type--if possible  
                        constructorArgs[j] = ConversionManager.getDefaultManager()
                                .convertObject(columnValue, parameterType);
                    }

                    *results.add(javaBeanClassConstructor.newInstance(constructorArgs));*
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Comment: what type `javaBeanClassConstructor.newInstance(constructorArgs)` is returning ?

Answer (score 5):

You should parameterize your ListEntity class

```
public class ListEntity<T extends SingularEntity>{

  public List<T> data;

  public ListEntity(List<T> data){
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks folks...much appreciated....So now the compilation is fine after the type safety....but while invocation of the method List<AuthorizationDTO> authData = DTOBuilder.newBuilder().DTOClassNameCalled(AuthorizationDTO.class).InputListCalled(lstObject).build();

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you've defined a `List<? extends SingularEntity>`, so you cannot add to this `List`.  Why not?  Because to the compiler, this `List` could be of *anything* that extends `SingularEntity`, say a new `MultipleEntity` class.  Java cannot allow you to add any arbitrary `SingularEntity` to any `List` of any possible subclass of `SingularEntity`.

To add to the `List`, just use a `List<SingularEntity>`.